# Powershell: "set home=PATH"

Tags: powershell, rsync, cwrsync

i try to migrate a cmd Batch file to powershell, but powershell don't accept the SET HOME command. The Script

```
SET HOME=c:\home\user
$destination=user@server:/cygdrive/c/Build
$source=/cygdrive/c/Build

rsync -av -e "./ssh" $source $destination
```

./ssh don't access to HOME, but the same Script run as cmd-Bash, any suggestion to set a Home Path like the cmd-bash SET HOME?

Regards 
Rene

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Env:HOME = 'C:\home\user'
$destination = 'user@server:/cygdrive/c/Build'
$source = '/cygdrive/c/Build'

rsync -av -e ./ssh $source $destination
```

What you have there is neither PowerShell nor a batch file, actually.

Answer (score 1):

`SET` is an alias for `Set-Variable`, which you can't use to set enviroment variables like in `cmd`, but there are solutions to do what you want, e.g. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2007/02/08/powershell-version-of-cmd-set.aspx)